# Calling async extension methods from separate assembly

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-standard

I've encountered a weird behavior regarding async extension methods in separate assemblies.

We have the following:

1. One assembly handling sending of `EventGridEvent`. Target is .NET Standard 2.0. This assembly references `Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid`.
2. One assembly using assembly no. 1. Target is .NET Framework 4.7.

For some reason, making synchronous methods from assembly no. 2 to assembly no. 1 results in weird behaviour. Consider the two functions we have in assembly no. 1:

```
    public async Task PublishAsync(...)
    {
        await _eventGridClient.PublishEventsAsync(_eventGridTopicHostName, ...);
    }

    public void Publish(...) 
    {
        _eventGridClient.PublishEventsAsync(_eventGridTopicHostName, ...).Wait();
    }
```

If we call the first method from assembly no. 2 with `PublishAsync().Wait()`, it will never return. `Publish()` will, however. But, if `Publish()` calls `PublishAsync().Wait()`, that method will also hang.

Worth mentioning is that `EventGridClient` contains `LongRunningOperationRetryTimeout` with default set to 30, which is ignored. It never returns.

Anyone have any idea what causes this behavior? A workaround is to copy code, but we would like to avoid that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you have inside `PublishEventsAsync`?

Comment: You should never call `Wait()` or `Result` on a task as it can lead to deadlocks and weird exception behaviour: https://medium.com/rubrikkgroup/understanding-async-avoiding-deadlocks-e41f8f2c6f5d

Comment: Why are you calling `Wait()`? This is a bad idea. You should await or ignore the task but not block on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the calling method was running on a UI thread. It was solved by wrapping the call like so: `Task.Run(() => ...).Wait()`

Answer (score 3):

You should never block on async code by calling `Wait()` or `.Result` on the returned `Task`. @Stephen Cleary explains why [on his blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

When `_eventGridClient.PublishEventsAsync` is called, the `SynchronizationContext` is captured. When the task completes, it waits for the context to become available but it never will since you are blocking it with your call to `.Wait()`. This leads to a deadlock.

You may get of out trouble by avoiding capturing the context by calling `ConfigureAwait(false)`:

```
public async Task PublishAsync(...)
{
    await _eventGridClient.PublishEventsAsync(_eventGridTopicHostName, ...)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

But the best solution is still not to block at all. Async code should be "async all the way" as explained in the linked blog post.

Comment: Plus 1 for "async all the way". Wait/Result are both purest evil.

Comment: Ideally, you should be async all the way, but if for some reason that's not possible, then it's no big deal to use `.Result` when you have no non-async version of a method you need to use.

Comment: @howcheng: So you are calling a deadlock "no big deal"? Interesting.

Comment: @mm8 I suppose I wasn't that clear. In the case where you start with a non-async method and you get to a point where you have no non-async version of a method you need, then using `.Result` will NOT cause a deadlock. Of course, it would be better to make the first item in the call stack async, but there are times when that's just not possible.